# Images not shown in IIS Local deploy but they shown on IIS Express in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 5 application. When I am running the project on IIS Express (default option), images are shown without problem. But after deploying on local IIS 8, the images are not shown. IIS and visual studio 2013 are on the same machine.

This image is not shown after deploying on Local IIS, but it is shown on IIS express ,

```
<img id="myimage"  src="@Url.Content('/Uploads/10.jpg')" />
```

This image is not shown on IIS express but it is shown on Local IIS,

```
<img id="myimage2" src="~/Content/Images/10.png" />
```

It is a strange situation, and what is your suggestion please?

Answer (score 7):

this [Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ajay_pathak/archive/2011/08/06/website-deployed-on-iis-7-5-not-showing-images-and-css-files.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) will help !

> The Proplem is : static content handler is missing in IIS.
>   To Solve it you need to enable a windows feature related to IIS Like in the picture below
>
> Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Common
>   HTTP Features -> Static Content
>   must be checked

[image: Windows features screenshot]

Comment: Please avoid providing answer containing only a link. If it gest broken the answer becomes useless.

Comment: pardon me i was not able to post the picture

Comment: @AndrzejBobak i could not post the image , this is the first question i help with , so i have no reputation enough to post a picture
thx for your notice bu the way :)
and i well edit my answer.

Comment: This helped !! Thank you.